# If $\phi$ is a homomorphism between cyclic groups $G$ and $F$, why must $|\phi(G)|$ divide $|G|$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

I am reading a solution to another problem that counts the homomorphisms. I don't get why $|G|/|\phi(G)|$, I get that $|F|/|\phi(G)|$ by Lagrange's theorem.

I guess it has to do with if $|G| = m$, then $\phi(g^m) = \phi(g)^m$, so there are $m$ copies which divide $|G|$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the first theorem of homorphism. It tells us that $G/ker(\phi)\cong Im(\phi)$ so if the group $G$ is finite so you' ll get the answer.

Comment: I forgot about the other arrows in the isomorphism theorem. Basically from my question, $\phi$ is an onto homomorphism, so the 1st isomorphism theorem implies $G/ker\phi \cong G \cong Im(\phi)$. Lagrange now implies $|G|/|Im(\phi)| = |ker \phi )|$ (how does one know $|ker \phi |$ is an integer?)

Comment: AH never mind, $\ker \phi$ is a normal **subgroup**, of course it has to be an integer. I am dumb, blah.

Comment: indeed the kernel is a normal subgroup of G and we know an integer as its order.

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi :G\to F$ then $G/\operatorname{ker \phi}\cong \operatorname{Im\phi}=\phi(G)\implies o(G/\operatorname{ker \phi})=o(\operatorname{Im \phi})\implies \dfrac{o(G)}{o(\operatorname {Im \phi)}}=o(\operatorname{ker \phi})$

and $\operatorname{ker \phi}$ is a subgroup of $G$